# CSS Dropdown on Image Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to get a logo to be a dropdown image when hovering on it, but it didn't work, can you help please?

```css
dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
dropdown:hover dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">


<head>
  <title>Evolutia sistemelor de operare Windows</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <img src="winlogo.png" alt="Windows Logo" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <img src="winlogo.png" alt="Windows Logo" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">Microsoft's OS Logo since Windows 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am new to CSS and my first project must include this hover on a image, I mention that I need to use my css from mystyle.css, not using `<style>` inside index page.

Comment: Posted a sample, use that and adjust it with which element that should show and which should not.

Comment: @V.Dum You should explain better what your goal is. There are two images in your source, both of which are visible. If that's not how you want it, if you want to hide one while showing the other, please say so in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the dot for class rules in your CSS, should be `.classname`

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ro">


<head>
  <title>Evolutia sistemelor de operare Windows</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <img src="winlogo.png" alt="Windows Logo" width="100" height="50">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <img src="winlogo.png" alt="Windows Logo" width="300" height="200">
      <div class="desc">Microsoft's OS Logo since Windows 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put dot in front of the class names in the CSS file.

Your code is:

```css
dropdown:hover dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

and you have to put it this way:

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

I think the best way to work with menu and dropdown is use the elements `ul li` intead. I advise you to use the front end libraries like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or even [Materialize-css](http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html), so easy to use and it follow a good practices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: Your opinion on what frameworks to use has nothing to do with the question being asked here.

Comment: Thanks! But it's a school project and I need to do it in this way, but thanks for great advices!

Comment: Paulie_D Charles McKelvey yout both are right. I already had an account in stackoverflow, but anway i lost it. Thanks, i edited the answer. @V.Dum just follow the advice from the LGSon.